# equals method for date comparison in the library java.util.Date

Tags: java

Is the method `java.util.Date` method `.equals` indifferent in what concerns the `date format` or not? I mean I've tried the `date.before` and `date.after` with different formats and they behaved normally, however, i am unsure about the `Date.equals` as I fear it behaves as the `java.lang.Object.equals`, I am seeking a firm and definitive answer.

Comment: You definitely can rely on `equals()` method to fulfil the equals "contract" - idempotent, meaningful equivalence, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the method java.util.Date method .equals indifferent in what concerns the date format or not?

A `Date` object doesn't *have* a format - it has no notion of where the information came from. It is *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1st 1970, midnight UTC). It also doesn't know about time zones. So you could have two `Date` objects created in very different ways which end up representing the same point in time - and `equals` would return `true` there.

It's really important to understand what information is and isn't part of the state of an object - particularly for date and time APIs, where it can be counterintuitive in some places. When in any doubt, read the documentation carefully. For example, from the [documentation for `Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

and in `equals`:

> Compares two dates for equality. The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not null and is a Date object that represents the same point in time, to the millisecond, as this object.
>
> Thus, two `Date` objects are equal if and only if the `getTime` method returns the same long value for both.

Comment: Damn you, mr Skeet! (-;

Answer (score 2):

You should really look at the [Date Class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). It states :

> public boolean equals(Object obj) Compares two dates for equality. The
>   result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Date
>   object that represents the same point in time, to the millisecond, as
>   this object. Thus, two Date objects are equal if and only if the
>   getTime method returns the same long value for both.

So, it doesn't behave in the same way the default *equals* in `Object` class behaves.

**with different formats and they behaved normally** : Since date is being converted to *absolute time*, the date format will not make any difference.

Comment: and can look over the implementation if in doubt http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Date.java#Date.equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @jdphenix - I was about to edit my answer to post the implementation :P. Anyways, I think, the link will suffice :P

Answer (score 1):

A java.util.Date is simply a wrapper around a long value representing the number of milliseconds since epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00.00). The equals method just compares these values.

See the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Compares two dates for equality. The result is true if and only if the
>   argument is not null and is a Date object that represents the same
>   point in time, to the millisecond, as this object. Thus, two Date
>   objects are equal if and only if the getTime method returns the same
>   long value for both.

And the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (of OpenJDK):

```
947     public boolean More ...equals(Object obj) {
948         return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
949     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i Guess this will help.

Equals method in date Compares two dates for equality. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Date object that represents the same point in time, to the millisecond, as this object. 
Thus, two Date objects are equal if and only if the getTime method returns the same long value for both.

Overrides: equals(...) in Object
Parameters:
obj the object to compare with.
Returns:
true if the objects are the same; false otherwise.
See Also:
java.util.Date.getTime()